# How to get a single item of a Java list in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I have a `java.util.list` that is supposed to contain exactly one item.

I want to extract this one item, and `assert/assume` this condition.

I could write something like this:

```
def single[T](list : java.util.List[T]) : T = {
    assume(list.size() == 1)
    list.get(0)
}
```

Is there something more idiomatic?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JavaConversions` and the `head` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def single[T](list : java.util.List[T]) : T = {
  assume(list.size == 1)
  list.asScala.head
}
```

Comment: Or `headOption` if you're not sure that the list is non-empty.

Comment: @PetrPudlák we are sure because of the call to assume

Comment: Or you could pattern match on `list.asScala` to both check for a single element and extract it at the same time: `list.asScala match { case Seq(hd) => hd ; case _ => ... }`.